# Can I make Qt Creator not start compiling if there is an error in the syntax?

Tags: qt-creator, syntax-checking

Qt Creator can locate errors in C++ code through some syntax checking. However it does not stop me from pressing the compile button. Is there any way to configure it to not start compiling if I have an error in my code.

For example it gives me a red underlined warning if I write `std:.cout` or miss an ending semicolon, etc. However I can still press the compile button and have to wait a couple a seconds before the compiler realizes something is fishy in code. Can I make it stop and tell me there is an error somewhere based on the syntax checking?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (yet)